# Entity Framework : SelfReferencing Optional Parent and Optional Child

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm currently developing a C# web application, following instructions from the old desktop application made by the company Delphi team!

The Delphi team created a relationship that I am having some trouble to config with Entity Framework, and since there are only three developers (including me) that are using Entity Framework, all of us with little experience, none of us managed to do this.

Basically, I have my clients, and those each client can have multiples 'MYENTITY'. This, I've had managed to do correctly.

The problem is: how can I make my

```
 MyEntityConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<MyEntity>
```

class configuration so, one `MYENTITY` have optional parent and optional children, but if it does have one, it must be the only one using it (or basically, a tree that the parent have one, and only one child).

[Structure on draw.io](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erp7k.png)

What I need is to my class looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQgWq.png) so in my html page, I can show a simple tree!

Answer (score 0):

What you need is relationship mapping. Check out these answers for details on how to map the different types of relationships:

[Mapping One to Zero or One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43370899/adding-0-1-relation-in-ef-code-first/43371838#43371838)

[One to One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44518699/ef-1-to-1-relationship/44519550#44519550)

[Many to Many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42853304/storing-additional-sets-of-information-for-a-many-to-many-relationship-using-a/42854751#42854751)